# Regarding User control design for win apps c#

Tags: c#, user-controls

i want to design a user control in win application such a way that when i drag & drop that user control on form it will just place at the top of the form just like menu control. so please tell me what extra code i need to add in my user control.

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the Dock property to Top

https://web.archive.org/web/1/http://articles.techrepublic%2ecom%2ecom/5100-10878_11-6165908.html